# low address bits of 192.168.1.1/24 are meaningless error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use NGINX to proxy all my usenet programs and add a ip range to bypass the basic auth while home.

here is an example of my set up

```
  location /plexpy {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/plexpy;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  satisfy any;
  allow 192.168.0.1/24;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    }
```

I've moved home and my new router (provided by my internet provider) runs on 19.168.1.254

so I went into my config and change the ip **allow** to **192.168.1.1/24** (my pc is running in 192.168.1.3 my ipad is on 192.168.1.14)

and I'm not able to bypass my basic auth and I see the following error in nginx

low address bits of 192.168.1.1/24 are meaningless

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you want 192.168.1.0/24?

Comment: Tried that and got the same error message

Comment: Are you sure? Why would it say "low address bits of 192.168.1.1/24 are meaningless" if you don't even have "192.168.1.1/24" in your configuration?

Comment: Sorry I meant I got “low address bits of 192.168.1.0/24 are meaningless”

Comment: Are you 100% sure about that? The message "low address bits of A.B.C.D/24 are meaningless" means that A.B.C.D needs to be an address A.B.C.0 (i.e. D needs to be 0). I'd be surprised if it complained when D was 0 (assuming it is /24). Might be worth trying again in case there was a typo?

Comment: hi, your right i added 192.168.1.0/24 and the error went away. yet i still cant by pass my basic auth. here is my set up  https://pastebin.com/YgATSgdy     ive increase the range to 48, yet everytime is still asks for user and password. could you please tell me ehwt im doing wrong